I'm using System.Text.Json.Serialization, Why [JsonPropertyName] is ignored for query params
I'm using System.Text.Json.Serialization and I have a class for query. In this class, I customize the JsonPropertyName attribute to "site".
public class SearchQuery
{
    [JsonPropertyName("site")]
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
}

My expected behavior is that when I hit the URL:
https://example.com/search?site=sandbox

the query.SiteName is "sandbox". However, [JsonPropertyName("site")] is ignored. The current behavior is that only when I hit the URL:
https://example.com/search?siteName=sandbox

the query.SiteName is "sandbox".
Is there any way to customize property names in query parameters using System.Text.Json.Serialization?

You're confusing query params binding and JSON serialisation which are two different things. Query params are not using JSON serialiser for binding.

Changing the name of a query string argument is not json related.
You need to apply a FromQuery attribute and set its Name property.
public class SearchQuery
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "site")]
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
}

